# How do i submit a iPhone 4 only app to the App Store?

Tags: iphone, ipad, store, platform

How do i submit a iPhone 4 only app to the App Store? As my app uses gyroscope functionality and Apple states that every app must run on iPad.Is there a way around this?

Thanks,
Lee

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You'll need to add the following to your plist file:

```
<key>UIRequiredDeviceCapabilities</key>
<array>
    <string>gyroscope</string>
</array>
```

Having this key will disallow any device without a gyroscope from downloading it.

Hope this helps!

Answer (score 7):

Apps don't *have* to run on the iPad, just as they don't *have* to run on all versions of the iPhone. Take a look at the [UIRequiredDeviceCapabilities](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#qa/qa2010/qa1397.html) key of the info.plist.

You'll need to add a "gyroscrope" key, and set it to YES.

Comment: A list of all keys for the capabilities can be found here: http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/General/Reference/InfoPlistKeyReference/Articles/iPhoneOSKeys.html

Answer (score 0):

Don't forget to consider the possibility a gyroscope may be added to the next iPad, so don't absolutely rely on the "gyroscope" value for "UIRequiredDeviceCapabilities" otherwise you may come unstuck.